# Inequality with integral

Tags: integration, inequality

Assume that F is a strictly increasing and continuous function , differentiable if needed,  over [0,a] such that F(0)=0 and F(a)=1, a>0. Prove or disprove :

$\int_0^a (F(x)-4F^2(x)+3F^3(x))\, dx\leqslant 0$

I proved this for concave functions and also it is true for many non concave functions, like $x^k, k>1$ but I don't have a general proof nor a counter example.

Any other sufficient conditions for F for this to be true would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct a counterexample, think about the map $y \mapsto y(1-4y+3y^2)$. This possesses roots at $y = 0,1/3,1$, and is positive on $(0,1/3)$ and negative on $(1/3,1)$. The problem can arise when $F$ spends time in $(0,1/3)$, contributing positive mass, or in $(1-\delta,1)$, contributing little negative mass. With this in mind, how about any function $F$ defined in such a way that $F(x) = 1/6 + x/1000$ for $x \in (\delta, 1-\delta)$, for $\delta > 0$ small (taking $a = 1$ for simplicity).

I checked this recipe for $\delta = 1/100$ and got that $$\int_{\delta}^{1-\delta} F(x) (1 - 4 F(x) + 3 F(x)^2) dx = 0.0680139$$, which means that no matter what values $F$ takes on the remainder of $[0,1]$, you'll still have an overall positive integral.

EDIT (Addendum): A sufficient condition for the inequality to hold:
Write $G(y) = y(1-4y+3y^2)$. Then $G$ has a maximum value $z^* > 0$ at some point in $(0,1/3)$. The condition will be of the form $F|_{(\delta, a-\delta)} \in (1/3 + \epsilon, 1 - \epsilon)$, where $\epsilon, \delta$ will be determined in terms of $z^*$. We have,
$$\int_0^a G \circ F(x) dx \leq z^* \delta + (a - 2 \delta) \max\{G(1/3 + \epsilon), G(1 - \epsilon)\}
$$
You can now specify $\epsilon, \delta$ so that the right hand side is dominated by zero.

Comment: To clarify, I'm saying that any $F$ satisfying the parameters of the problem which takes on the above form on the interval $(1/100, 99/100)$ will break the inequality. You can fill in $[0,1/100]$ and $[99/100]$ however you want to.

Comment: Good idea but it is not clear to me why (1/100,99/100) has to dominate (99/100,1). Derivative may be too high at 1. Will check your example by filling in (99\100,1).

Comment: The global minimum of $y(1-4y+3y^2)$ is about -.3 and so the contribution from the endpoints can be no worse than $-.3 * 2/100 = -.006$.

Comment: Moreover, this problem doesn't have anything to do with the derivative of $F$. Which derivative are you talking about?

Comment: Now, I see. If the calculation is correct, this shpuld be okay. Thank you for your work. Any idea on possible sufficient condition for F for the inequality to be true?

Comment: Well, roughly speaking, you'd want a condition that prevents the construction above from working. What I have in mind is some condition that says $F$'s values leave the interval $[0,1/3]$ 'quickly', and that the values of $F$ spend 'enough' time in $(1/3,1)$ in such a way that they don't linger at the endpoints of this interval for too long (so that the contribution would be near zero). You could turn this into some kind of sufficient condition given by an inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I completed the example you made and inequality fails. So, this is a valid example. The worrying thing for me about the sufficient condition argument you were thinking is that this inequality holds $F(x)=x^{k}$, for all $k$. Hence, for large $k$, $F$ values are almost always below $1/3$. For example, for $k=1000$, $F$ is below $1/3$ when $x<0.9989$. So, there seems to be additional reason for the inequality to hold.

Comment: @EmrePer Yeah, that makes sense; the 'sufficient' condition I mentioned is very much 'nonnecessary'. I'm sorry to say however that it's not likely you'll find a nice 'necessary' condition aside from the integral inequality itself...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have to be true. If $1>c-4c^2+3c^3>0$ for $0<c<1$, for example $c=1/4$, the integral of the constant function $F(x)=c-4c^2+3c^3$  from $0$ to $1$ is greater than $0$. Now just approximate $f(x)=c$ by a differentiable function that satisfies your criteria. One example (hope I didn't make a mistake !)
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
c\sin(\pi/2\cdot x/\epsilon),\quad 0\leq x <\epsilon\\
c,\quad \epsilon\leq x\leq 1-\epsilon\\
1-(1-c)\cos(\pi/2\cdot (x-(1-\epsilon))/\epsilon),\quad 1-\epsilon<x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
You can choose $\epsilon$ as small as you want, so the integral is as close to $c-4c^2+3c^3$ as you want.